# ora-01422 error by a procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

Below code throwing ORA-01422 error. As my code uses `select ... into`  I come to know it is fetching more than one row from the table but how can I overcome this by eliminating select into statement. Here is the code:

```
PROCEDURE Call_Transaction ( Transaction_Name Varchar2, Transaction_Type Varchar2, Form_Open_Type Varchar2 ) IS
BEGIN

Declare
  M_Transaction_Name U_Transaction_Master.Transaction_Name%Type := Upper(Transaction_Name);
  M_Transaction_Cd   U_Transaction_Master.Transaction_Cd%Type;

  T_Transaction_Cd   U_Transaction_Master.Transaction_Cd%Type;
Begin

  Select Transaction_Cd Into M_Transaction_Cd From U_Transaction_Master
  Where Transaction_Name = M_Transaction_Name ;
  Begin
    Select Transaction_Cd Into T_Transaction_Cd From U_User_Wise_Transactions  
    Where Login_Cd = :Global.Login_Cd And Transaction_Cd = M_Transaction_Cd And
    Inst_Cd = :Global.Company_Cd And
    To_Char(Valid_Upto_Date,'DD-MM-YYYY') = '31-12-9999';

    If Transaction_Type = 'FORM' And Upper(Form_Open_Type) = 'CALL_FORM' Then
         DECLARE
         id FormModule; 
       BEGIN
         id := Find_Form(M_Transaction_Name); --<Replace your form name>--
         IF Id_Null(id) THEN
             Call_Form(:Global.Forms_Path||M_Transaction_Name||'.Fmx');
         ELSE
             Go_Form(Id) ;
         END IF ;
       END ;       
    Elsif Transaction_Type = 'FORM' And Upper(Form_Open_Type) = 'OPEN_FORM' Then
              Open_Form(:Global.Forms_Path||M_Transaction_Name||'.Fmx');
    Elsif Transaction_Type = 'REPORT' And Upper(Form_Open_Type) = 'RUN_PRODUCT' Then
          Declare
            Pl_Id ParamList;
          Begin 
            Pl_Id := Get_Parameter_List('tmpdata'); 
            IF NOT Id_Null(Pl_Id) THEN 
               Destroy_Parameter_List( Pl_Id ); 
            END IF; 
            Pl_Id := Create_Parameter_List('tmpdata'); 

            ADD_Parameter(pl_id,'Inst_Cd',TEXT_PARAMETER,:GLOBAL.Company_Cd);
            ADD_Parameter(pl_id,'Ac_Year_Cd',TEXT_PARAMETER,:GLOBAL.Ac_Year_Cd);
            ADD_Parameter(Pl_Id,'INST_NAME',TEXT_PARAMETER, :Global.Company_name);
            ADD_Parameter(Pl_Id,'ADDRESS',TEXT_PARAMETER, :Global.Address);
            ADD_Parameter(pl_id,'FOOTER',TEXT_PARAMETER,:GLOBAL.Footer);

            Run_Product(REPORTS,:Global.Reports_Path||M_Transaction_Name, SYNCHRONOUS, RUNTIME,
                        FILESYSTEM, Pl_Id, NULL); 
          End;
    End If;

  Exception
    When No_Data_Found Then
         Message('Sorry..., You Do Not Have Authorization For : '||M_Transaction_Cd||' Transaction Code...');
         Raise Form_Trigger_Failure;
  End;

Exception
  When No_Data_Found Then
       Message('The Transaction Cd Not Exists In Transaction Master, Please Contact Administrator...');
       Raise Form_Trigger_Failure;
End;

END;
```

How can I rewrite the code to resolve ORA-01422 error?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` might do it.  You need to ensure that the query only returns one row.

Comment: I guess you should first think whether you expect multiple rows to be returned. I sound to a 'bad design' to me more than a SQL problem.

Comment: @Joe: that is only a solution if all the rows have the same value.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Correct, that's why I said it *might* do it.  No way to tell from just looking at the script.

Comment: Which SELECT...INTO... is throwing the ORA-01422?

Answer (score 0):

In oracle, you can keep the select into statement and limit the number of rows using ROWNUM:

```
Select Transaction_Cd Into M_Transaction_Cd From U_Transaction_Master
  Where Transaction_Name = M_Transaction_Name 
    and ROWNUM < 2;
```

Comment: @Wernfried if you don't like that solution you need to come up with a SQL statement that guarantees that only a single row is selected. E.g by including the PK in the where clause or by applying aggregate functions. But as you are the only one who knows your data, you are also the only one to know how to do that.

Comment: In case I don't have to read each record and just have to know if at least one row exist, I usually do following approach: `DECLARE CURSOR curSEL IS SELECT ...; SEL curSEL%ROWTYPE; BEGIN OPEN curSEL; FETCH curSEL into SEL; IF curSEL%FOUND THEN ...;`. Yes, it is more code to type but in my opinion the smarter way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to change exception handling logic:

- enclose in `begin ... exception ... end` only part that really can
  through exception;
- handle too_many_rows exception

.

```
PROCEDURE Call_Transaction ( Transaction_Name Varchar2, Transaction_Type Varchar2, Form_Open_Type Varchar2 ) IS
BEGIN

Declare
  M_Transaction_Name U_Transaction_Master.Transaction_Name%Type := Upper(Transaction_Name);
  M_Transaction_Cd   U_Transaction_Master.Transaction_Cd%Type;

  T_Transaction_Cd   U_Transaction_Master.Transaction_Cd%Type;
Begin

  --  1st select with error analysis
  begin
    Select Transaction_Cd Into M_Transaction_Cd From U_Transaction_Master
    Where Transaction_Name = M_Transaction_Name ;
  exception
    when No_Data_Found then begin
       Message('The Transaction Cd Not Exists In Transaction Master, Please Contact Administrator...');
       Raise Form_Trigger_Failure;
      end;
    when too_many_rows then begin 
       -- What really must be done in this case?
       Message('There are too many Transaction Cd's with passed name In Transaction Master, Please Contact Administrator...');
       Raise Form_Trigger_Failure;
    end;
  end;

  -- 2nd select with error analysis
  begin
    Select Transaction_Cd Into T_Transaction_Cd From U_User_Wise_Transactions  
    Where Login_Cd = :Global.Login_Cd And Transaction_Cd = M_Transaction_Cd And
          Inst_Cd = :Global.Company_Cd And
          To_Char(Valid_Upto_Date,'DD-MM-YYYY') = '31-12-9999';
  Exception
    When No_Data_Found Then begin
         Message('Sorry..., You Do Not Have Authorization For : '||M_Transaction_Cd||' Transaction Code...');
         Raise Form_Trigger_Failure;
      end;
    When too_many_rows Then begin
         -- What really must be done in this case?
         Message('Sorry..., there are some misconfiguration in Authorization Settings For : '||M_Transaction_Cd||' Transaction Code. Please contact Administrator.');
         Raise Form_Trigger_Failure;
      end;
  End;

  If Transaction_Type = 'FORM' And Upper(Form_Open_Type) = 'CALL_FORM' Then

     ---[... all other code skipped ...]---

  End If;


END;
```

After refactoring you need to answer a question about what really must be performed in situations when more than one row found and handle it according to nature of implemented task.

If you worried about method that you can use to detect presence of values and determine it's count then you may look at [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115747/is-the-use-of-select-count-before-select-into-slower-than-using-exceptions).